# AWS Lambda pandas.to_sql creates SQL Table (MySql) but do not insert data to created table

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda for file preprocessing and writing final dataframe to external mysql table.
For the connection, I use sqlalchemy connection. The code is looks like this :

`

```
def connect_mysql(credentials: dict, dataframe: pd.DataFrame, table_name: str):
    engine = f'mysql+pymysql://'+credentials['user']+':'+credentials['passwd']+'@'+ credentials['host'] +':'+credentials['port']+'/'+credentials['db']+''    engine_corp = create_engine(engine, paramstyle="format")
    connection = engine_corp.connect()
    dataframe.to_sql(name=table_name, con=connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    return f'Inserted to {table_name}'
```

There is no error in cloudwatch logs, lambda creates table for dataframe but not insert data into that table

There is no any exact solution or even a problem like that in entire web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to use sqlalchemy instead of pymysql.
This will auto-commit the transactions and below is an example of how you make use of the context manager to write a clean code

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    df1.to_sql(name= 'test1',schema='test', con=conn , if_exists='replace', index=False)
    df2.to_sql(name= 'test1',schema='test', con=conn , if_exists='append', index=False)
```